# How to access getPreferenceManager from preference fragment in sub package?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have an activity that is loading preference fragments. I have my package organized by all activities are in one package, then all Preference Fragments are in another package.

When calling `getPreferenceManager()` inside my Preference fragment, I get a null value.

If I put the Activity loading the PreferenceFragments into the same package as the PreferenceFragments, it works. But that is not how I want it. I want all activities in one package, and all preference fragments in another. I'm guessing this isn't possible?

Comment: `getPreferenceManager()` is available for the `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment` derived objects - so does your Preference fragment extend `PreferenceFragment` or just `Fragment`? I don't think packages matter, as long as you import them correctly where you need to use them.

Comment: it extends `PreferenceFragment`. But like I said, if I move both the activity and the fragments together in the same package, everything works as expected. If I separate the fragments package from the activities package, then I get a `null pointer exception` on `getPreferenceManager`

Comment: Please share the extended code snippet that results in `getPreferenceManager` returning `null`, show the package name, the class definition and other relevant parts of the code - it's a bit difficult to try and visualize it.